# Local notifications stopped working, can't figure out why

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I got local notifications working for my iOS project some time last year before putting it aside, but when I came back a few weeks ago I noticed that they no longer worked. I've dug around for a few days and I'm completely stumped. The badge still updates properly with a background fetch, but the notification alert is no longer sent. Here's a minimal setup of what I have for testing.

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert], categories: nil))

    return true
}    

 func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {    
   let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
   localNotification.alertAction = "Message"
   application.presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)

   completionHandler(.NoData)
 }
```

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling/reinstalling the app (device and simulators)
- Changing the Bundle identifier
- Disabling/re-enabling background fetch capability
- Present delayed local notification by adding the fireDate attribute
- Tried willFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- I've debugged it and am 100% certain that performFetchWithCompletionHandler executes when I simulate background fetch and that presentLocalNotificationNow is called

Setup:

- Xcode 7.3.1 (started on previous release, probably 6.x.x)
- Swift 2.2 (started the project on 2.1 and was functional)
- iOS 9 (started the project on 8 and was functional)

Did something change in the API that I missed, or is there some error in what I'm doing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: try this :  `let mySettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert , .Badge],categories: nil as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)`

Comment: `cat as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>` gives an error, but I tried with `Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>()` instead and it didn't work either

Comment: yeah u have to set `categories: nil` have edited the above comment check

Comment: No luck, `nil as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>` produces "Expression type 'Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>?' is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILocalNotification requires that `alertBody` be set in order to display. So having the following works:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {    
   let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
   localNotification.alertBody = "You have a notification"
   localNotification.alertAction = "Message"
   application.presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)

   completionHandler(.NoData)
}
```